# Method reference to local class constructor

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

There are several similar questions on SO about method reference to local class constructor, but I'd like to clarify slightly other thing. Consider following piece of code:

```
static Callable gen(int i) {
    class X {
        int x = i;
        public String toString() { return "" + x; }
    }
    return X::new;
}

...

System.out.println(gen(0).call()); 
System.out.println(gen(1).call());
```

Obviously this will printout

```
0
1
```

It turns out, that `X` class has constructor of the form `...$X(int)` (you can find it via `X.class.getDeclaredConstructors()`).

But what is interesting here, is that returned lambdas (or method references) aren't simple reference to constructor `...$X(int)` like, for example, `Integer::new`. They internally invoke this constructor `...$X(int)` with predefined argument (`0` or `1`).

So, I'm not sure, but looks like this kind of method reference is not precisely described in JLS. And there is not other way except this case for local classes, to produce such kind of lambdas (with predefined constructor arguments). Who can help clarify this?

To be precise:

- where is in JLS such kind of method reference described?
- is any other way to create such method reference to arbitrary class constructor with predefined arguments?

Comment: *It is also clear, that X class has constructor of the form ...$X(int)* - I see no such constructor. Actually, I see no constructor.

Comment: @Bohemian It actually is, look at `X.class.getDeclaredConstructors()`

Comment: That's because it is implicitly generated by the compiler, but you can find it in the bytecode.

Comment: @Clashsoft but I'm asking about where such kind of method reference actually described in JLS

Comment: @Clashsoft I just inspected the bytecode and didn't find an `int` arg constructor. I found only a no-args one: `invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V` (1.8.0_66-b18)

Comment: Thats the invocation of the super constructor.

Comment: @Bohemian `Constructor<?>[] declaredConstructors = X.class.getDeclaredConstructors();   System.out.println(declaredConstructors[0].getParameterTypes()[0]);` this will printout `int`

Comment: @Clashsoft sorry? Of which super constructor? This is static method

Comment: @Andremoniy did you look under JLS section [15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)? I don't know if there is a direct explanation

Comment: @Clashsoft Sure I did

Comment: Every constructor calls the super constructor of the super class (in your case `java.lang.Object`) either implicitly or explicitly (by using `super()` in the constructor body).

Comment: @Clashsoft OK, and how this fact is related to constructor reference?

Comment: Got it. `0: aload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field val$i:I` is the implied constructor accepting an int

Comment: @Andremoniy you tell me "sorry? Of which super constructor?"

Comment: @Bohemian Yeah! And could you please give me explanation to my questions?

Comment: This is the comments after all

Comment: @Clashsoft OK, just misunderstanding.

Comment: "It is also clear, that X class has constructor of the form". Honestly, I don't find that particularly clear :)! Maybe you could edit in your question the generated bytecode with the constructor you are talking about.

Comment: @Tunaki Well, I thought this is clear from investigating constructors of given class :)

Comment: @Andremoniy In that case, you could say everything is clear once you look in the right place ;)

Comment: @Tunaki OK, I will edit my question and will say: *Turns out, that...* :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are focusing too much on irrelevant low level details. On the byte code level, there might be a constructor accepting an `int` parameter, but on the language level, you didn’t specify an explicit constructor, hence, there will be a default constructor without any arguments, as with any other class.

This should become clear when you write the pre-Java 8 code:

```
static Callable<Object> gen(int i) {
    class X {
        int x = i;
        public String toString() { return "" + x; }
    }
    X x=new X();
    …
```

You instantiate `X` by its default constructor, not taking any arguments. Your local class *captures* the value of `i`, but how it does so on the low level, i.e. that `X`’ constructor has a synthetic `int` parameter and the `new` expression will pass the value of `i` to it, is an implementation detail.

You can even add an explicit constructor as

```
        X() {}
```

without changing anything.

Obviously, you can also write the expression `new X()` inside a lambda expression here, as expressions don’t change their semantic when being placed inside a lambda expression:

```
    return () -> new X();
```

or use it’s short-hand form, the method reference

```
    return X::new;
```

There is nothing special about it, the behavior is understandable even without referring to the specification, if you forget about the distracting low level details. `X` may capture as many local variables as you like, the constructor’s number of parameters doesn’t change (on the language level).

Comment: I'm not sure, that it is just like `Callable() { X call() { return new X(); }}`, because it implicitly invokes synthetic constructor with predefined parameter.

Comment: @Andremoniy: I don’t get your objection. All non-reflective instantiations will invoke the synthetic constructor with the captured value of `i` as the argument. If your define the callable as a local class, it has to capture `i` as well, so it complicates matters on the low level, but what’s the question?

Comment: thank you. I've just realized obviousness of this case. It was my late-night delirium :))

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is defined in the JLS section [§15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3):

> If the form is ClassType :: [TypeArguments] new, the body of the invocation method has the effect of a class instance creation expression of the form new [TypeArguments] ClassType(A1, ..., An), where the arguments A1, ..., An are the formal parameters of the invocation method, and where:
>
> - **The enclosing instance for the new object, if any, is derived from the site of the method reference expression, as specified in §15.9.2.**
> - The constructor to invoke is the constructor that corresponds to the compile-time declaration of the method reference (§15.13.1).

Although this talks about enclosing **instances**, captured variables and parameters are not mentioned *in §15.13.3*.

As for your second question, you need to manually capture and change the parameter:

```
static Callable gen(int i) {
    final int i1 = someCondition() ? i : 42;
    class X {
        int x = i1; // <-
        public String toString() { return "" + x; }
    }
    return X::new;
}
```

Comment: Well, I thought this is about *are the formal parameters of the invocation method*, like for `Integer::new` constructor, you have to assign it to `Function<Integer, Integer>` but not to `Callable`.

Comment: @Clashoft your second part of answer unfortunately describes same way. I mean way for creating such kind of method references for arbitrary class (I will clarify it in question)

Comment: +1 for your question, but I accepted answer of @Holger due to its more detailed explanation. Thank you too